# Modifying List CSS Code

Tags: html, css

I am using the CSS code at: http://jsfiddle.net/HequH/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="vertmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#vertmenu {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#vertmenu ul {
    list-style-image: url('http://s9.postimg.org/5pcchngqz/triangle.png');
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
}
#vertmenu ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#vertmenu ul li.hover {
    list-style-image: url('https://s22.postimg.org/jx9f9v5a5/square.png');
}

#vertmenu ul li:first-child a {
    border-top: 0px;
}
#vertmenu ul li a {
    font-size: 13px;
    display: block;
    border-top: 2px dashed #000000;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:100%;
    line-height:46px;
    height:46px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#vertmenu ul li a:hover, #vertmenu ul li a:focus {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

I want the bullet area to match the area of each List Item.  (In other words, I want to add a dashed border below the bullet, and make the background area behind the bullet change to grey on hover so that it is uniform with the text.)

Is it also possible to change the bullet to the following image on hover?

[image]

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Post your code in your question. Thanks.

Comment: He obviously has a minimal understanding, he has tried `#vertmenu ul li.hover {
list-style-image: url('http://s22.postimg.org/jx9f9v5a5/square.png');
}` but it isn't working.

Comment: `#vertmenu ul li.hover`. `hover` is a pseudo class, so should be `:hover`

Comment: Also, the first bullet should be on the `<li>` and not the `<ul>`

Comment: This looks like multiple questions in one post. It may be better to split it into multiple problems and have one question for each problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generic  Pseudo element solution.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yHfxC)

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#vertmenu {
  margin: 25px;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 0;
  list-style:none;
  padding-left:5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height:40px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}

li:before {
  content:" ";
  width:25px;
  height:32px;
  margin-top:4px;
  background-image: url('http://s9.postimg.org/5pcchngqz/triangle.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;

}
li:hover {
  background:lightgrey;
}


li:hover:before {
    background-image: url('http://s22.postimg.org/jx9f9v5a5/square.png');
}


a {
  line-height:32px;
  height:32px;
  text-decoration:none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-lefT:10px;
}
```

Comment: Can we align the list flush to the left of the page? There is a tiny bit of white space at the top that should also be filled in: http://s16.postimg.org/uox7lt9yd/css_list.png

Comment: Yes, you can...but what I offered was a generic solution. By all means feel free to change some of the values to suit. **It's probably just he margin-bottom.**

Comment: Thanks so much. This is great because it works in IE too. The only thing I'm having trouble doing is aligning it completely to the left. I tried changing the margins to 0 but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 3):

Your code was slightly wrong. You were using `.hover` instead of `:hover`.

This property: `list-style-position:inside;` will solve the bg color issue.

[**JSFiddle updated**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/HequH/8/)

**CSS**

```
#vertmenu ul li {
list-style-image: url('http://s9.postimg.org/5pcchngqz/triangle.png');
list-style-position:inside;
margin: 0 0 0 30px;
padding: 0px;
border: none;
}
#vertmenu ul li {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#vertmenu ul li:hover {
list-style-image: url('http://s22.postimg.org/jx9f9v5a5/square.png');
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to display properly in Firefox. I'm using 23.0.1.

Comment: That being the case, I would abandon list images completely and use pseudo elements to recreate the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is simple, you had a typo.

This:

```
#vertmenu ul li.hover {
  list-style-image: url('http://s22.postimg.org/jx9f9v5a5/square.png');
}
```

Should be:

```
#vertmenu ul li:hover {
  list-style-image: url('http://s22.postimg.org/jx9f9v5a5/square.png');
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/HequH/6/)

**In all** reality you could just achieve this with pure css and not images.

---

For the first part of your question,

I am using a pseudo element on the li to achieve the desired effect.

The new css:

```
#vertmenu ul li:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30px;
    border-top: 2px dashed #000000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

#vertmenu ul li:hover:before {
    z-index: -1;
    background: #cccccc;
}

#vertmenu ul li:first-child:before {
    border-top: 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/HequH/11/)

Comment: This is great but it doesn't help with the first part of my question, which is changing the area around the bullet to match the area of the list item.

Comment: @user3216933 Refer to my edit, I used a pseudo element to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. However, the bullets can change background color on their own in Firefox.  The background color should change for both the text and bullet on hover.

Comment: @user3216933 Here you go mate, http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/HequH/12/. It was being caused by the hover state on the a tag or to keep it on the a tag, http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/HequH/13/.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Sadly it doesn't work in IE. :/